# Pandas DataFrame: apply function to all columns

Tags: python, dataframe, pandas

I can use `.map(func)` on any column in a df, like:

```
df = DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3,4,5,6], 'b':[2,3,4,5,6,7]})

df['a'] = df['a'].map(lambda x: x > 1)
```

I could also:

```
df['a'], df['b'] = df['a'].map(lambda x: x > 1), df['b'].map(lambda x: x > 1)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to apply a function to all columns or the entire frame (without a loop)?

Answer (score 99, accepted):

If I understand you right, you're looking for the [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) method.

```
>>> print df
   A  B  C
0 -1  0  0
1 -4  3 -1
2 -1  0  2
3  0  3  2
4  1 -1  0
>>> print df.applymap(lambda x: x>1)
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1  False   True  False
2  False  False   True
3  False   True   True
4  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 18):

From `0.20.0` onwards, you can use `transform`

```
In [578]: df.transform(lambda x: x > 1)
Out[578]:
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1  False   True  False
2  False  False   True
3  False   True   True
4  False  False  False

In [579]: df
Out[579]:
   A  B  C
0 -1  0  0
1 -4  3 -1
2 -1  0  2
3  0  3  2
4  1 -1  0
```

And, for this simplistic case, why not just use `df > 1` ?

```
In [582]: df > 1
Out[582]:
       A      B      C
0  False  False  False
1  False   True  False
2  False  False   True
3  False   True   True
4  False  False  False
```

Answer (score 1):

##### From version 2.1.0 of pandas, use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.map.html) instead of [`applymap`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html)

`applymap` has been deprecated.

```
In [101]: df.map(lambda x: x > 1)
Out[101]: 
           A      B      C
    0  False  False  False
    1  False   True  False
    2  False  False   True
    3  False   True   True
    4  False  False  False
```

##### Prefer using the comparison operators directly over using map:

```
In [102]: df > 1
Out[102]: 
           A      B      C
    0  False  False  False
    1  False   True  False
    2  False  False   True
    3  False   True   True
    4  False  False  False
```

Also, you could use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) or [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html).

If you don't need additional parameters, they will seem to be basically the same, except for using the comparison operator which is the recommended choice in OP's case.

Read [the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) for more details