# Counting list entries in specific columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, count

I have a Dataframe like this

```
               1               2         ...            9
0            ['1']              []                    ['9']
1            ['1'] ['2', '2', '2']               ['9', '9']
2       ['1', '1'] ['2', '2', '2']                       []
3  ['1', '1', '1']           ['2']                       []
```

I want to count the occurences in each column so that the output would be like this

```
               1               2         ...            9
0              1               0                        1
1              1               3                        2
2              2               3                        0
3              3               1                        0
```

This seems to work with the following code

```
df.1.apply(lambda x: x.count('1'))
```

but how can I automate it for all my columns so I don't have to run the above code for each individual column?

In addition I used

```
df.1.apply(lambda x: x.count('1')).sum()
```

to count the total for the rows which seems to be giving the right answer. Is there a better way though?

Comment: `applymap` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741092/pandas-dataframe-apply-function-to-all-columns

Comment: `df.applymap(len)`