# Apply function to all columns of data frame python

Tags: python, pandas, function, lambda

I have two dfs

```
xx
```

| AVERAGE_CALL_DURATION | AVERAGE_DURATION | CHANGE_OF_DETAILS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 267 | 298 0 | 0 |
| 421 | 609.33 | 0.33 |
| 330 | 334 0 | 0 |
| 240.5 | 666.5 | 0 |
| 628 | 713 0 | 0 |

and

```
NoC_c
```

| AVERAGE_CALL_DURATION | AVERAGE_DURATION | CHANGE_OF_DETAILS |
| --- | --- | --- |
| -5.93 | -4.95 | 0.90 |
| 593.50 | 595.70 | 1.00 |

I want to return 1 if the `xx` column contains the range within `NoC_c` (where column names are the same

I can do this for one column

```
def check_between_ranges(xx, NoC_c):
    ranges = NoC_c['AVERAGE_CALL_DURATION']
    
    if (xx['AVERAGE_CALL_DURATION'] >= ranges.iloc[0]) and (xx['AVERAGE_CALL_DURATION'] <= ranges.iloc[1]):
        return 1
    return xx['AVERAGE_CALL_DURATION']

xx['AVERAGE_CALL_DURATION2'] = xx.apply(lambda x: check_between_ranges(x, NoC_c), axis=1)
```

However, I need remove the element of manually specifying the column name as the actual dfs contain many more columns.

I have tried

```
a = NoC_c.columns

def check_between_ranges(xx, NoC_c):
    ranges = NoC_c[a]
    
    if (xx[a] >= ranges.iloc[0]) & (xx[a] <= ranges.iloc[1]):
        return 1

xx.apply(lambda x: check_between_ranges(x, NoC_c[a]), axis=1)
```

However, I get the error
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()`.

I tried the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12741092/pandas-dataframe-apply-function-to-all-columns), although, they were unsuccessful

Also read [this](https://www.learndatasci.com/solutions/python-valueerror-truth-value-series-ambiguous-use-empty-bool-item-any-or-all/) to address the specific error but didn't aid in my issue

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-2affca771555>", line 10, in <module>
    xx.apply(lambda x: check_between_ranges(x, NoC_c[a]), axis=1)

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 7552, in apply
    return op.get_result()

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 185, in get_result
    return self.apply_standard()

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 276, in apply_standard
    results, res_index = self.apply_series_generator()

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\apply.py", line 305, in apply_series_generator
    results[i] = self.f(v)

  File "<ipython-input-11-2affca771555>", line 10, in <lambda>
    xx.apply(lambda x: check_between_ranges(x, NoC_c[a]), axis=1)

  File "<ipython-input-11-2affca771555>", line 6, in check_between_ranges
    if (xx[a] >= ranges.iloc[0]) & (xx[a] <= ranges.iloc[1]):

  File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 1330, in __nonzero__
    f"The truth value of a {type(self).__name__} is ambiguous. "

ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Edit:: Many thanks to @jch for the solution. I'm re-posting here as I had to modify some of the syntax for it to work with my datasets

```
def check_between_ranges(x):
    v = []
    
    for c in x.index:
        if (x[c] >= NoC_c.iloc[0][c]) & (x[c] <= NoC_c.iloc[1][c]):
            v += [1]
        else:
            v += [x[c]]
            
    return pd.Series(v, index=x.index)


xx.apply(check_between_ranges, axis=1)
```

Comment: that error raises when you're expecting a single value to be either (True, False) but you're actually feeding an object with multiple values, like a Series of Boolean values. Can you add the full trace so we can see what line is raising the Error?

Comment: @Yuca I have amended the post to include the traceback

Comment: as the other answer in your post, you have to apply a function `(xx[a] >= ranges.iloc[0]).all()` or `(xx[a] >= ranges.iloc[0]).any()` depending on your solution logic. That should answer the original question. If there are other issues after you solve for that, then you need to ask another question since the original is solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this work for you?

**Comparison Function**

```
def check_between_ranges(x):
    v = []
    
    for c in x.index:
        if (x[c] >= NoC_c.at[0,c]) & (x[c] <= NoC_c.at[1,c]):
            v += [1]
        else:
            v += [x[c]]
            
    return pd.Series(v, index=x.index)
```

**Execution**

```
xx.apply(check_between_ranges, axis=1)
```

**Result**

```
   AVERAGE_CALL_DURATION  AVERAGE_DURATION  CHANGE_OF_DETAILS
0                    1.0              1.00               0.00
1                    1.0            609.33               0.33
2                    1.0              1.00               0.00
3                    1.0            666.50               0.00
4                  628.0            713.00               0.00
```

Comment: I was getting an error and had to modify the .at on line 5. Otherwise, a working solution. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have almost the solution. Try to add `.all()`, docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.all.html):

```
def check_between_ranges(xx, NoC_c):
    ranges = NoC_c[a]
    
    if (xx[a] >= ranges.iloc[0]).all() & (xx[a] <= ranges.iloc[1]).all():
        return 1
```

Comment: When running the above only a series is returned. Instead, the output should retain the shape of the original df only with the new imputation

Output:

4537   nan
7245   nan
2334   nan
7023   nan
2152   nan